# Quickbooks Exceptions & Errors (How to tell what they are?)

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm using the Quickbooks PHP SDK.

I'm currently trying to run a command below:

```
$res = $dataService->Add($customerObj);
```

I know the command is throwing an exception right now, but I can't tell what the exception is or how to tell what went wrong?

How do I do this?

Note:: I will figure out what is wrong with customerObj on my own to save you guys time, just need to figure out how to find out what the errors are that are being returned back to me.

Update:: Its an Ids Exception Error, but do not know what this means?

As Requested here is the rest of the code:

```
$requestValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(              
                    gdizDecrypt($qbkeys->oauthtoken),
                    gdizDecrypt($qbkeys->oauthtokensecret), 
                    OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, 
                    OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET
                );

                $serviceContext     = new ServiceContext($qbkeys->realmid, $qbkeys->datasource, $requestValidator); 
                $dataService        = new DataService($serviceContext);

                $customerObj = new IPPCustomer(); 

                $customerObj->GivenName     = $client->contactfirstname.' '.$client->contactlastname;
                $customerObj->FamilyName    = $client->contactlastname;
                $customerObj->DisplayName   = $client->contactfirstname.' '.$client->contactlastname;   
                $customerObj->PreferredDeliveryMethod   = 'Print';
                $customerObj->BillWithParent            = 'false';
                if($client->active == '')
                {
                    $customerObj->Active                    = (bool)false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $customerObj->Active                    = 'true';
                }

                $phoneObj = new IPPTelephoneNumber();
                $phoneObj->FreeFormNumber = $client->contactphonenumber;

                $emailObj = new IPPEmailAddress();
                $emailObj->Address = $client->contactemail;

                $addrObj = new IPPPhysicalAddress();
                $addrObj->Line1 = $client->contactaddress;

                $customerObj->PrimaryPhone      = $phoneObj;
                $customerObj->PrimaryEmailAddr  = $emailObj;
                $customerObj->BillAddr          = $addrObj;
```

Comment: How do you know it's throwing? "find out what the errors are that are being returned back to me" - What does it say?

Comment: I wrapped it in a try{} catch{} statement and the catch is triggering

Comment: And what's the `message` / stack trace?

Comment: Well its kind of long, but this is what it is, {"command":"Failed","message":"Quickbooks API Error Occured.","exception":"IdsException Object\n(\n    [message:protected] => 2015-09-03 13:53:37 - \/home\/betapoolserviceu\/public_html\/vendor\/quickbooks\/DataService\/DataService.php - 340 - CheckNullResponseAndThrowException - Response Null or Empty\n    [string:Exception:private] => \n    [code:protected] => 0\n    [file:protected] => \/home\/betapoolserviceu\/public_html\/vendor\/quickbooks\/Core\/CoreHelper.php\n    [line:protected] => 95\n    [trace: ... etc

Comment: It's an IdsException Object right now, when I print out the e using print_r(e,true)

Comment: Only thing is I'm not sure if I'm doing that correctly.  I looked up that error and not sure what it means for quickbooks.

Comment: So there's your error. What's the question? :)

Comment: I suppose my question is what is the IdsException Error mean for quickbooks? I'm not sure what to do from here.  I can't tell what I did wrong in my code from what I'm given back in the exception.

Comment: What is `$dataService` and what is `$customerObj`? Please add essential code parts plus the exception to your question :)

Comment: I posted the code as an edit to the question, hope that helps.  This code oddly enough works elsewhere in my project which is why I didn't post it.  This is why I was hoping quickbooks had an easier way to tell me what the error was.

Comment: Found an answer, thanks for your help m02ph3u5!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out the problem.  After much hunting I found an article here.

https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1016393-checknullresponseandthrowexception-response-null-or-empty

You need to modify your sdk.config file to the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <intuit>
    <ipp>
      <!--Json serialization not supported in PHP SDK v2.0.5 -->
      <message>
        <request serializationFormat="Xml" compressionFormat="None"/>
        <response serializationFormat="Xml" compressionFormat="None"/>
      </message>
      <service>
        <baseUrl qbd="https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" qbo="https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" ipp="https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/" />
      </service>
      <logger>
        <!-- To enable/disable Request and Response log-->
        <requestLog enableRequestResponseLogging="false" requestResponseLoggingDirectory="/IdsLogs" />
      </logger>
    </ipp>
  </intuit>
</configuration>
```

My code that worked before was on production, and if you are using development sandboxes which I was, you need to change the correct references.

Hope this information helps someone.